# alinear formulario bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Como puedo centrar mi formulario de bootstrap, ya que todo está a la derecha, tal vez sea que estoy colocando mal el tamaño de las celdas, este es mi código

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" style="margin:0 auto">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-8 control-label">Nombres</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-8 control-label">Apellidos</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-8 control-label">Correo Electrónico</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-8 control-label">Teléfono Celular</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono_cel" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success left">Registrarse</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quieres que todo este centrado o alineado a la izquierda?

Comment: @JuanGlezz que todo este centrado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con tu código solo es cuestión de jugar con las grids de Bootstrap, así que puse todas las columnas en 4 para darle el efecto de centrado aunque tambien puedes usar la clase `col-lg-offset-2` en cada `label` o puedes hacer uso de [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="form-horizontal" style="margin:0 auto">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Nombres</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Apellidos</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Correo Electrónico</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Teléfono Celular</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono_cel" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success left">Registrarse</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar de la siguiente manera:

```
   <div class="text-center">
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-8 control-label">Nombres</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-8 control-label">Apellidos</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-8 control-label">Correo Electrónico</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-8 control-label">Teléfono Celular</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono_cel" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success left">Registrarse</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
</div>
```

o asi

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-8 control-label">Nombres</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-8 control-label">Apellidos</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-8 control-label">Correo Electrónico</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-8 control-label">Teléfono Celular</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono_cel" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success left">Registrarse</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Intenta aplicar las [alineaciónes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) que tiene [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) son muy utiles, solo tienes que colocar la clase en el elemento que desees alinear, algo asi:

```
<div class="text-center">Centra el contenido del div</div>
```

Espero te funcione.

Comment: creo que no funcionaria como tiene el su código ya que esta usando el 100% del `div`, tendría que reducir el tamaño de la columna de la etiqueta `label` y se alinearía correctamente en el centro, pero aun así depende de los anchos

Comment: Esta clase solo se aplica a elementos inline, y no es lo que está solicitando la persona que pregunta. Los elementos `form` y `div` son elementos block.

Comment: En realidad que lo uso en muchas ocasiones para centrar contenido, no es algo que sea muy estético pero funciona, Muchas gracias por la aclaración @Shaz